# perl: printing object properties

Tags: perl, reference

I'm playing a bit with the Net::Amazon::EC2 libraries, and can't find out a simple way to print object properties:

This works:

```
my $snaps = $ec2->describe_snapshots();
foreach my $snap ( @$snaps ) {
  print $snap->snapshot_id . " " .  $snap->volume_id . "\n";
}
```

But if I try:

```
 print "$snap->snapshot_id $snap->volume_id \n";
```

I get

```
Net::Amazon::EC2::Snapshot=HASH(0x4c1be90)->snapshot_id
```

Is there a simple way to print the value of the property inside a print?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not in the way you want to do it. In fact, what you're doing with `$snap->snapshot_id` is calling a method (as in `sub`). Perl cannot do that inside a double-quoted string. It will interpolate your variable `$snap`. That becomes something like `HASH(0x1234567)` because that is what it is: a `bless`ed reference of a hash.

The interpolation only works with scalars (and arrays, but I'll omit that). You can go:

```
print "$foo $bar"; # scalar
print "$hash->{key}"; # scalar inside a hashref
print "$hash->{key}->{moreKeys}->[0]"; # scalar in an array ref in a hashref...
```

There is one way to do it, though: You can reference and dereference it inside the quoted string, like I do here:

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now();
print "${\$dt->epoch }"; # both these
print "@{[$dt->epoch]}"; # examples work
```

But that looks rather ugly, **so I would not recommend it**. Use your first approach instead!

If you're still interested in how it works, you might also want to look at these Perl FAQs:

- [What's wrong with always quoting "$vars"?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What%27s-wrong-with-always-quoting-%22$vars%22?)
- [How do I expand function calls in a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string?)

---

From [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References):

> Here's a trick for interpolating a subroutine call into a string:
>
> ```
> print "My sub returned @{[mysub(1,2,3)]} that time.\n";
> ```
>
> The way it works is that when the @{...} is seen in the double-quoted
>   string, it's evaluated as a block. The block creates a reference to an
>   anonymous array containing the results of the call to mysub(1,2,3) .
>   So the whole block returns a reference to an array, which is then
>   dereferenced by @{...} and stuck into the double-quoted string. This
>   chicanery is also useful for arbitrary expressions:
>
> ```
> print "That yields @{[$n + 5]} widgets\n";
> ```
>
> Similarly, an expression that returns a reference to a scalar can be
>   dereferenced via ${...} . Thus, the above expression may be written
>   as:
>
> ```
> print "That yields ${\($n + 5)} widgets\n";
> ```

Comment: And if I'd remembered that it was a method call rather than a property, I might have figured it out - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 14):

`$snap->volume_id` is not a property, it is a method call. While you could interpolate a method call inside a string, it is [exceedingly ugly](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string?).

To get all the properties of an object you can use the module `Data::Dumper`, included with core perl:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($object);
```

Comment: The package name must also match the file name: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35106674/1544937

Answer (score 2):

Stick with the first sample you showed. It looks cleaner and is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering this because it took me a long time to find this and I feel like other people may benefit as well.

For nicer printing of objects use Data::Printer and p():

```
use DateTime;
use Data::Printer;
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time );
p($dt);
```

Comment: `Data::Printer` seems to be better than `Data::Dumper` when debugging data on screen (not only it's colored, but also formatting is much easier to read by human).

Answer (score 2):

The PERL translator has limited depth perception within quotes. Removing them should solve the problem. Or just load the real values into a simple variable that you can print within the quotes. Might need to do that if you have objects which contain pointers to other objects:

```
SwissArmyChainSaw =/= PureMagic:
print("xxx".$this->{whatever}."rest of string\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$snap` is being interpolated inside the string, but `$snap` is a reference.  As `perldoc perlref` tells us: "Using a reference as a string produces both its referent's type, including any package blessing as described in perlobj, as well as the numeric address expressed in hex."

In other words, within a string, you can't dereference `$snap`.  Your first try was the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most comment, stick to concatenation for easy reading. You can use

> say

instead of print to spare of using the "\n".