# Undefined subroutine &main::First called at hello.pl line 6

Tags: perl

I am facing one issue with my perl code.
I have created one package 'Welcome.pm' and using that in a script 'hello.pl'. But getting below error 'Undefined subroutine &main::First called at hello.pl line 6'
I looked at other answers as well but still couldn't figure out what is wrong with code.

Can anyone please help?

perl module Welcome.pm

```
package Welcome;

use strict;
use warnings;
use base 'Exporter';
my @ISA = qw(Exporter);
my @EXPORT = qw(First);  

sub First{
print "welcome\n\n";
}


1;
```

perl script hello.pl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use UsersModules::Welcome qw(First);
use strict;
use warnings;

First();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file name and the package name must tie up, so the statement

```
package UsersModules::Welcome
```

must appear in the file

```
UsersModules/Welcome.pm
```

The `@ISA` array needs to be a *package variable* (declared with `our`) instead of a *lexical variable*, but rather than manipulating it directly it is best to

```
use parent 'Exporter';
```

However, the best choice is to *import* the `import` subroutine from `Exporter` instead of inheriting it, so you can write just

```
use Exporter 'import';
```

The `@EXPORT` array must also be a package variable

Like this

```
package UsersModules::Welcome;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter 'import';

our @EXPORT = qw/ First /;

sub First{
    print "welcome\n\n";
}


1;
```

If you want to import a subroutine named in the `@EXPORT` list, then there is no need to mention it in your `use` statement. (If you had put it in the `@EXPORT_OK` list then you would have to name it in the `use` statement.)

Together with the above module, this main program works fine

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use UsersModules::Welcome;

First();
```

#### output

```
welcome
```

Comment: @ArhanKhan See: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)