# Add to integer within string?

Tags: string, perl, increment

I would like to make a string by incrementing a variable within the string.

eg.

```
$result = "Result: $amount++";
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: `$amount++; $result = "Result: $amount";`?

Comment: @TLP I think he wants it inline, in the same expression.  That being said, I see nothing wrong with your solution (and I actually prefer it).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is the same expression. Only separated by a semi-colon. The differences are purely philosophical.

Comment: `$result = sprintf "Result: %s", $amount + 1;` is one statement, but it does not work any better.

Comment: This is a strange request. What do you hope to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: Are you packing a counter inside of a string, where the rest is some description of it?

Comment: `$result = "Result: ".++$amount;`

Comment: @ceving, `++$amount` and `$amount++` return different values.

Comment: @ikegami It is not clear what has been asked. "incrementing a variable within a string" sounds to me that the result string should contain the incremented value, which means that the value needs to be incremented first.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done using trickery.

```
$result = "Result: ${\( $amount++ )}";
```

But why would you want to???

```
$result = "Result: ".$amount++;
```

Comment: Can you please explain the first line of code in your answer?

Comment: @CJ7 I know, this is an old thread but it showed up as _"recently active"_. The first line is explained in the FAQ [How do I expand function calls in a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-expand-function-calls-in-a-string?) and in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13239936/5830574).

Answer (score 1):

I take it that you have a string that already contains a 'number' (string of digits), and you want to increment that number within.

You'd have to extract the "number" first, in one way or another, since it is merely a string of chars when inside a string; then increment it and join it all back. I'll take it that it is a string of digits bounded by non-digits

```
my ($pre, $num, $post) = $str =~ m/(\D*)(\d+)(\D*)/;
$str = $pre . ($num+1) . $post;
```

This makes a critical assumption that the word contains a string of digits in only one place and no digits elsewhere, since if that were not the case the problem would be ill posed.

Just for the curiousity of it I'd like to add a bit to this. A part of a string can be accessed by [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html), and that function can be manipulated as an `lvalue` (can be assigned to).  So, if you were to know the starting position and the length of your "number" (what can be found in various ways) you could cram the above process in one statement, if you must

```
substr($str, $num_beg, $num_len) = substr($str, $num_beg, $num_len) + 1;
```

or, equally bad

```
substr($str, $num_beg, $num_len) = ($str =~ m/(\d+)/)[0] + 1;
```

Now your starting `$str` string contains the "number" within it incremented. However, this is plain nasty and I cannot recommend any of it. Finally, you can of course find `$num_beg` and `$num_len` on the fly, inside of `substr`, but that is just too much as the poor string would be processed three times in a single statement.  (Also, this changes your `$str` in place, which your question hints is not what you want.)

---

*Added*   Regex provide the capability to run code in the replacement part, by using `/e` modifier.

```
my $str = "ah20bah";
$str =~ s/(\d+)/$1+1/e;
say $str;  # it's 'ah21bah'
```

See this [`in perlrequick`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) and [`in perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify a number in a string, you have to use the `e` modifier for the `s` operation. This makes Perl evaluating the replacement as an expression.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
$_ = "Result: 1\n";
s/\d+/$&+1/e;
print;
```

It is documented in the Perl [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators).